# Transition to another route when the top resource is accessed, but not when a nested route is accessed

Tags: ember.js

I have the following route defined:

```
SettingsApp.Router.map(function () {
    ....
    this.resource('profile', function () {
        this.route('user'),
        this.route('company')
    });

});

SettingsApp.ProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function () {
        this.transitionTo('profile.user');
    },
    model: function () {
        return Ember.A([
            Ember.Object.create({title:"User", link:"#/profile/user"}),
            Ember.Object.create({title:"Company", link:"#/profile/company"})
        ]);
    }
})
```

`#/profile` redirects to `#/profile/user`, as expected, *but* the problem is that `#/profile/company` does *also* redirect to `#/profile/user`. It seems the resource redirect is followed whenever I access any url below that resource.

Why is this? How can I redirect *only* the top level `#/profile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move your `redirect()` to the `profile` reource's `index` route, `ProfileIndexRoute`, which will cause it to trigger only if you browse to `#/profile` and allows you to access `#/profile/user` and `#/profile/company` without issues:

```
SettingsApp.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('profile', function () {
        this.route('user');
        this.route('company');
    });

});

SettingsApp.ProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    //redirect: function () {
    //    this.transitionTo('profile.user');
    //},
    model: function () {
        return Ember.A([
            Ember.Object.create({title:"User", link:"#/profile/user"}),
            Ember.Object.create({title:"Company", link:"#/profile/company"})
        ]);
    }
});


SettingsApp.ProfileIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function () {
        this.transitionTo('profile.user');
    },
});
```

[Example JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/181/edit)

Hint: set `LOG_TRANSITIONS: true` on your `Application` to show you which routes are being accessed through the router. This is extremely helpful for debugging issues like this one.

```
SettingsApp = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
```

Comment: But one question: what is the difference between the `ProfileIndexRoute` and the `ProfileRoute`. You mentioned `ProfileIndexRoute` is triggered when `#/profile` is accessed. When is `ProfileRoute` triggered? When I had no `ProfileIndexRoute`, it was triggered on `#/profile` too.

Comment: @gonvaled as for the question about the difference between `PostsRoute` and `PostsIndexRoute` see here:http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/. And one last hint, if you hardcode your links to routes, be aware that if your routes structure changes you have to find all occurences of you links and rewrite them too

Answer (score 1):

The `redirect` in your `ProfileRoute` is a hard redirect, this means that regardless what nested routes/resources you have it will always redirect to `profile.user`. To have a different behavior you should remove the `redirect` hook and provide links from your parent template or navigation to your sub-resources, e.g.

```
{{#linkTo profile.user}}User{{/linkTo}}
{{#linkTo profile.company}}Company{{/linkTo}}
```

This will generate the following HTML markup:

```
<a href="/user">User</a>
<a href="/company">Company</a>
```

And in the case you want to pass a model in the route transition you could in your template setup things like:

```
{{#linkTo profile.user user}}User{{/linkTo}}
{{#linkTo profile.company company}}Company{{/linkTo}}
```

In the case you do pass a model you need to change the router map accordingly:

```
SettingsApp.Router.map(function () {
  ....
  this.resource('profile', function () {
    this.route('user', { path: "/user/:user_id" }),
    this.route('company', { path: "/company/:company_id" })
  });
});
```

This will generate the following HTML markup:

```
<a href="/profile/user/1">User</a>
<a href="/profile/company/1">Company</a>
```

And lastly if you redirect to `profile.user` or `profile.company` you will also need templates for this routes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works, but I have to manually code the menu, which was previously  done with the helper `{{view Bootstrap.Tabs}}`, and I would like to keep that.